# NodeJS express Authentication using POST returns Error Cannot Set Headers After they Are Sent

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, authentication, express

I am trying to build a basic Auth using post

```
 app.post("/api/auth",function(req,resp)
 {

   var username = req.body.username||req.param('username');
   var password = req.body.password||req.param('password');
   log("Performing Log Check");
   log(username + " "+password);

     var sent ={};
     sent.status =false;
     sent.authenticated = false;

     var query = {}
     query.sql= "SELECT * FROM voix_auth";
     query.timeout= 4000; // 40s
     connection.query(query, function (error, rows, fields)
     {
       if(!error)
       {
           var i=0;
           while(i!=rows.length)
           {
               if(rows[i].username  == username  &&  rows[i].password == password)
               {
                 log(rows);
                 sent.status = true;
                 sent.authenticated = true;
                 sent.token = tokenData;
                 log(sent);
                 break;
               }
             i+=1;
            }
          resp.send(sent);
         }  //Error Ends
         else
         {
           log("Error Occured");
         }

      });  //connection Query
      log(sent);
      resp.send(sent);
  });
```

The issue here is that I get Cannot set header After They are Sent.
So when I remove `resp.send()` this error is gone.

But if the response I get is always false even though the user is Authenticated.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant send out multiple responses.

Things to change

- Change query to something like `select ONLY_STUFF_YOU_NEED from table where username & passwords match`. Take care of sql injection.
- Wrap the query in a function that returns back a valid `user` object ONLY if auth matches. Move it outside the controller. Example + shameless plug - https://github.com/swarajgiri/express-bootstrap/tree/master/core
- After auth is done, send the response using `res.send`